# How to Extract JSON from MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to extract the new status value from the below JSON

```
{"old_status":"Testing(PhaseI)","new_status":"Production(PhaseII)","user":"Developer","reason":null}
```

so the output required is **Production(PhaseII)**, pls note that the new_status's values are completely dynamic , how to do this using JSON_EXTRACT()

Comment: `new Stage`?? I assume you mean `new_status`

Comment: If you know you need to use `JSON_EXTRACT()` why are you not looking that up in the manual or finding a tutorial to show you how to use that function

Comment: `SELECT json_column->>'$.new_status' ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`field``, '$.new_status'))
```